# How to get WooCommerce creds in Oauth in React Native?

Tags: wordpress, react-native, woocommerce, oauth

I am building an app in React Native for a Wordpress site that uses WooCommerce.

On the WooCommerce REST API guide it says:

> "You must use OAuth 1.0a "one-legged" authentication to ensure REST
>   API credentials cannot be intercepted by an attacker. Typically you
>   will use any standard OAuth 1.0a library in the language of your
>   choice to handle the authentication..."

Through searching I've found the `react-native-oauth` package, as well as a few instructions, and they all refer to the `ios` and `android` folders in my project. I don't have these folders in my project! I think this is from using Expo to create my app. I imagine it's not possible to use this plugin with my app the way it is?

I've seen the `oauth-1.0a` package as well, and a few other small tutorials, mostly for setting up Facebook or Twitter login or something like that. I'm a little unclear if it's all the same process for something like accessing the WooCommerce REST API.

How can I do this without the `ios` folder, and/or how do I get that folder in my project?